# How come using np.linalg.norm introduces unseen numerical inequality but writing it out does not?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Let's say I have these two variables:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 0,  1, 10,  2,  5]])

b = np.array([[ 0,  1, 18, 15,  5],
              [13,  9, 23,  3, 22],
              [ 2, 10, 17,  4,  8]])
```

**Method 1**

```py
m1 = -np.linalg.norm(a[:, np.newaxis, :] - b[np.newaxis, :, :], axis=-1) ** 2 / 2
```

**Method 2**

```py
m2 = -np.sum(np.square(a[:, np.newaxis, :] - b[np.newaxis, :, :]), axis=-1) / 2
```

Both of these outputs look alike (at least according to `print()`):

```py
array([[-116.5, -346. ,  -73.5]])
```

But

```py
>>> np.array_equal(m1, m2)
False
```

What makes it interesting is that defining a literal to check equality leads to:

```py
>>> sanity_check = np.array([[-116.5, -346. ,  -73.5]])
>>> np.array_equal(sanity_check, m1)
False
>>> np.array_equal(sanity_check, m2)
True
```

How come using the method with `np.linalg.norm` is the odd one out? If `m1` is unequal, how come its `print()` looks equal?

Comment: `np.allclose` is recommended when comparing float arrays, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tiny amount of numerical error in the actual values:

```
>>> m1.tolist()
[[-116.49999999999999, -346.0, -73.5]]

>>> m2.tolist()
[[-116.5, -346.0, -73.5]]
```

This is because:

```
>>> np.sqrt(8**2 + 13**2)**2
232.99999999999997

>>> 8**2 + 13**2
233
```

---

NumPy's [`printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions) controls how many digits are printed. By default, they are:

```
>>> np.get_printoptions()
{'edgeitems': 3, 'threshold': 1000, 'floatmode': 'maxprec', 'precision': 3, 'suppress': False, 'linewidth': 75, 'nanstr': 'nan', 'infstr': 'inf', 'sign': '-', 'formatter': None, 'legacy': False}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, floating point arithmetic only provides approximate results. Very good approximations, but different depending on how the calculations were performed.

There should be a canonical answer to this sort of questions pointing to [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/).